# Hacer UPDATE desde una variable SQL SERVER 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server, update

Tengo que hacer un UPDATE a 4 campos en un a tabla, en lo cual esos campos tengan el mismo valor de un campo de la misma tabla llamada FechaT, pero al guardar el valor en una variable me da error.

Este es el Query:

```
DECLARE @FECHA DATETIME;
SET @FECHA = (SELECT FECHAT FROM SAACXC);
UPDATE SAACXC SET FechaE = (SELECT FECHAT FROM SAACXC)
```

Answer (score 0):

La definición de tú problema no es del todo precisa.

Si esta fuera la tabla:

```
create table saacxc (id int, fechat datetime, fechae datetime, fechaa datetime, fechab datetime);
GO
insert into saacxc(id, fechat)
values
(1,'20211208 18:00'),
(2,'20211208 18:30'),
(3,'20211208 18:45'),
(4,'20211208 18:59');
GO
```

[image: Result 1]

Tenemos actualmente 4 filas, y queremos que las columnas `fechae`, `fechaa` y `fechab`, tengan el mismo valor que `fechat`, para su fila.

```
UPDATE SAACXC 
    SET FechaE = fechat,
        fechaa = fechat,
        fechab = fechat;
```

[image: Result]

Como se aprecia en la imagen, cada columna, coge el valor de la columna `fechat` de su misma fila.

Volviendo al escenario inicial.

```
Delete from saacxc;
insert into saacxc(id, fechat)
values
(1,'20211208 18:00'),
(2,'20211208 18:30'),
(3,'20211208 18:45'),
(4,'20211208 18:59');
```

Si lo que necesito es que se modifiquen todas las filas, con el valor de una variable, es necesario identificar el valor único a asignar en la variable.

```
DECLARE @FECHA DATETIME;
SET @FECHA = (SELECT FECHAT FROM SAACXC WHERE ID = 2);
UPDATE SAACXC SET FechaE = @FECHA;
```

[image: Result2]

Por tanto he identificado el valor único de la asignación a la variable. Luego updateo la columna conforme al valor de la variable.

Volviendo al escenario inicial.

```
Delete from saacxc;
insert into saacxc(id, fechat)
values
(1,'20211208 18:00'),
(2,'20211208 18:30'),
(3,'20211208 18:45'),
(4,'20211208 18:59');
```

Si por el contrario, necesito actualizar una o varias columnas para una fila determinada, con un valor determinado, identificado en una variable.

```
DECLARE @FECHA DATETIME;
SET @FECHA = (SELECT FECHAT FROM SAACXC WHERE ID = 2);
UPDATE SAACXC SET FechaE = @FECHA
    where ID = 3
```

[image: Result4]

El problema final, es que estás asignando a una variable que solo puede contener un valor, un conjunto de valores.

Dice el código expuesto.

Asigna en @fecha el siguiente valor ( y en la select hay un conjunto de fechaT)
Esto es un conjunto en un solo sitio no entra.